# Flask JWT Authentication works in localhost but breaks when deployed

Tags: reactjs, flask, flask-jwt-extended

I have built a REST API using `Flask` and used `flask_jwt_extended` to do the authentication side of things. This API I have deployed on [Render](https://dashboard.render.com/) using `gunicorn`.

Additionally, I have a small `React` app that leverages the API.

The problem I am having is as follows:
Making requests through my React app on `localhost` works but making requests to the Render deployed API always returns `401 Unauthorized`.

I have checked that cookies are being set on the browser correctly in my React app.

I have searched the internet thoroughly but am still lost. Would appreciate the help.